# How can I reset an Inspect Element tab position in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

As you can see, the position of a sub-elements tab (including Computed, Styles, Layout, Event Listeners, etc.) is accidentally at the right of the HTML area. Before, that tab was placed under of the HTML area.

How can I reset it? I've tried to use right-click and drag the tab, but it still didn't work.

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to reduce the width of the Chrome DevTools small window to restore it (when the small window of the DevTools is at a large width, this will also be moved to the right).